# What is the Javascript syntax when a "get" function appears inside an object?

Tags: javascript

i run into this code and i'm not familiar with the syntax - What is the "get: " stands for? and why is it written this way?

```
var newVar = {

        get: function fn() {

            return this.val;
        },
        val: 43
    };

    var child = Object.create(newVar);
    child.val = 333;

    var child2 = Object.create(child);



    console.log(child.get() + child2.get());
```

Comment: It's just the name of an object property, in the same way that "val" is the name of an object property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about `get`. In your example, it is simply a property of an object called `get`. It could just as easily by called `getMeOutOfHere`:

```
var newVar = {

  getMeOutOfHere: function () { console.log('we\'re leaving'); }

}
```